# override in cart page in the custom module in the magento 2 is not work?

Tags: magento2, cart, overrides, magento-2.0.7

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart">
        <action method="setTemplate">
           <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Ocodewire_Designtool::cart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Comment: please provide full code to debug more. Your question is not understand by user.

Comment: please describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: in above this is my checkout_cart_index.xml in my custom module and in template i make phtml and call here in xml but in cart page not show anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the `<body>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Ocodewire_Designtool::cart.phtml</argument>
           </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

See devdocs for instructions on page configuration:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-types.html#Page-configuration-structure-and-allowed-layout-instructions